# Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location

Tags: python, openssl, compilation

I need to install several Python modules on a RHEL where I don't have root access. At least one of the modules also needs access to `Python.h`.

In this case I find that the best thing is to install python and it dependencies in `~/local`. It usually just works, but this time Python fails to build the SSL module (see details below). Here's the trace of what I'm doing.

So I  downloaded python 6 source and off I went:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/fds/rms/local
make >& make.log
```

An inspection to log reveals that ssl module has not been compiled, but there is no mention of the cause (no other occurence of ssl in make or configure):

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel
_hashlib           _sqlite3           _ssl   <----------
```

So I figure, python is not finding any ssl library at all (which is strange, but hey...). So I download openssl-0.9.8r and

```
./config --prefix=/home/fds/rms/local shared
make
make install
```

Now back to Python, I ./configure and make again. It fails, but this time it's different:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib           _ssl
```

A closer inspection to the log file reveals this:

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/home/fds/rms/installers/Python-2.6.6/Modules/_ssl.o -L/home/fds/rms/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/_ssl.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So now it's picking up the library but not quite getting it right (the file is there where is should be):

```
$ find /home/fds/rms/local -iname libssl.so.0.9.8
/home/fds/rms/local/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

Next thing is tracing make and see where is it looking for the file:

```
$ strace -f make 2>&1 | grep libssl.so.0.9.8
[pid  5584] open("/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/lib64/tls/x86_64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/lib64/tls/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/lib64/x86_64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or   directory)
[pid  5584] open("/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/tls/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] write(1, "*** WARNING: renaming \"_ssl\" sin"..., 131*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[pid  5584] open("/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/tls/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] open("/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  5584] write(1, "*** WARNING: renaming \"_hashlib\""..., 135*** WARNING: renaming "_hashlib" since importing it failed: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Mhhh, it's looking in all the wrong places. I try to give a hint:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/fds/rms/local/include -I/home/fds/rms/local/include/openssl" LDFLAGS="-L/home/fds/rms/local/lib" ./configure --prefix=/home/fds/rms/local
```

But nothing changes, and `make` does not seem to try `/home/fds/rms/local/lib` at all.

I haven't done this in years, so maybe I'm overlooking something. Can anyone help with the problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36774171/1959808

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546). Looks like the same problem.

Comment: Building with custom OpenSSL is now well documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#custom-openssl

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to edit `Modules/Setup.dist` to specify the location of OpenSSL if it is not in the standard location. From [Getting SSL Support in Python 2.5.1](http://paltman.com/2007/nov/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/):

> If you find yourself on a linux box needing ssl support in python (to
>   use a client in things like httplib.HTTPSConnection or
>   imaplib.IMAP4_SSL), then let me save you a couple of hours of hunting
>   around the web (of course if you have found this then that means
>   you've done some level hunting already!).
>
> You'll know if you need ssl support compiled into your python
>   installation if you get the following exception message:
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ssl'
>
> In order to make that go away so you can continue happily slinging
>   python code, you'll need to first make sure you have OpenSSL
>   installed. By default it is installed from source at: /usr/local/ssl
>
> If that directory doesn't exist, then grab the source package.
>
> Do the standard:
>
> ```
> tar zxf openssl-0.9.8g.tar.gz
> cd openssl-0.9.8g
> ./config
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> Then grab the python sources for 2.5.1 and: tar zxf Python-2.5.1.tgz
>   && cd Python-2.5.1
>
> Then you need to edit the Modules/Setup.dist:
>
> ```
> 204:# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
> 205:# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
> 206:SSL=/usr/local/ssl
> 207:_ssl _ssl.c \
> 208:    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
> 209:    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
> ```
>
> If you installed OpenSSL in the default locations you can just
>   uncomment lines 206-209, then:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> Then verify your installation with:
>
> ```
> python /usr/local/lib/python2.5/test/test_socket_ssl.py
> test_rude_shutdown ...
> test_basic ...
> test_timeout ...
> ```

Make sure the changes to `Modules/Setup.dist` get picked up by cleaning the source root (e.g. `make distclean`) and run `configure` and `make` again.

Comment: On RHEL, where is the **standard** location? I have installed openssl and openssl-devel rpm with yum

Comment: Works for python3.6 too ^^

Comment: not work on python3.7 when openssl not installed in standard location

Comment: @Xiao There might be a change introduced in 3.7 which might be the reason for that. You might want to work through https://bugs.python.org/issue32694 to get further information.

Comment: If still getting **checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host in libssl... no**, try: `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH ./configure` and `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH make`.

Comment: This worked for installing Python 3.7.4 on RHEL. With default openssl install, I had to change SSL line: SSL=/etc/pki/tls, uncomment out the next three lines and I had to run sudo yum install openssl-devel

Comment: Setup.dist only needed editing up to Python 2.5. **This is no longer needed in any more recent versions**.

Answer (score 32):

@PeterVanGalen [has a good method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60272727), and is relevant as of 2021, but I disagree with some details.

His method of modifying the `Modules/Setup` file results in the libssl.so and libcrypto.so libraries becoming dynamic dependencies of the `python` binary itself. This is not as intended -- those are supposed to be dependencies of python importable `.so`'s, like `_ssl.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

His method also doesn't include a solution for how `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` will be found at runtime, rather than build time. This matters if they are in some unusual, custom path, or else python will either not run at all or be unable to `import ssl`. You could solve it in lots of ways (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ld.so.conf` come to mind) but I opted to use rpath, so that the `.so` files can always be found in their custom location when I use this python, but will otherwise stay out of the way.

This is my modification of @PeterValGalen's approach:

```
# First we need openssl installed in a custom location...
tar zxf openssl-1.1.1j.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1j
./config --prefix=/my/weird/path --openssldir=/my/weird/path/ssl
make
make install  # Add `sudo` if needed for permission to /my/weird/path.
cd ..

# Now the python part...
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.2/Python-3.9.2.tgz
tar xf Python-3.9.2.tgz
cd Python-3.9.2
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=/my/weird/path/lib" ./configure --with-openssl=/my/weird/path
make
make install  # Add `sudo` if needed for permissions.
```

When done this way, the openssl libs are not dependencies of the python binary, but are dependencies of the `_ssl*.so`

```
$ ldd ./python | grep weird
# [Nothing]

$ ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/_ssl.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  | grep weird
        libssl.so.1.1 => /my/weird/path/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f733ee73000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /my/weird/path/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f733e9ab000)
```

And it works:

```
$ ./python -c "import ssl; print('yay')"
yay

$ ./python Lib/test/test_ssl.py
# ... lots of good stuff...
OK (skipped=10)
```

Comment: I use python 3.6.8, it show `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-openssl `

Comment: This `configure` command-line option was added in CPython 3.7.

Comment: Fantastic! This should be the accepted answer for current versions of Python.

Comment: It works, but I had to make a symbolic link in my openssl install named `lib` pointing to `lib64` just next to it. In case it can help somebody.

Comment: @Welgriv thank you! I just want to let you know that you helped me. Even though I have been caught by this lib64 and lib thing in the past, cuda did it to  me and I forgot about it.

Answer (score 24):

On Linux Red Hat 7.7 x86_64, the following worked to install **openssl-1.1.1d** and **Python-3.8.1** in my home directory (/home/unix/vangalen):

**Install OpenSSL**
[source1](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL) [source2](https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/)

```
cd ~
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz
cd /home/unix/vangalen/openssl-1.1.1d
./config --prefix=/home/unix/vangalen/openssl --openssldir=/home/unix/vangalen/openssl
make
make test
make install
```

**Install Python**
[source2](https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/) [source3](https://passingcuriosity.com/2015/installing-python-from-source/) [source4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246699/python-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-share)

```
cd ~
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tgz
tar xf Python-3.8.1.tgz
```

Modify Python-3.8.1/Modules/Setup in a text editor. If this file doesn't exist you may need to go through a failed run first. Uncomment lines and adjust the alias for SSL in lines 206 to 213::

> ```
> _socket socketmodule.c
>
> # Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
> # socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
> SSL=/home/unix/vangalen/openssl
> _ssl _ssl.c \
>   -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
>   -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
> ```

```
cd ~/Python-3.8.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/unix/vangalen/openssl/lib
./configure --prefix=/home/unix/vangalen/py-381 --with-openssl=/home/unix/vangalen/openssl
make
make test
make install
```

Answer (score 9):

in the Bourne shell (/bin/sh or /bin/bash):

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ make
```

in the C-shell (/bin/csh or /bin/tcsh):

```
% setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
% make
```

Comment: This, in combination with a local install of OpenSSL, did the trick for me.

Comment: This seems to work only at compile time, when running python later without the export the library is not found anymore!

Answer (score 4):

For me editing `Modules/Setup` was not enough as `_hashlib` module still ended up using the wrong OpenSSL version; and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was not taken into account at runtime on my SLES system.

What worked was to statically link the local OpenSSL to both `_ssl` and `_hashlib` by editing `setup.py` as per [GitHub patch: eddy-geek/ python_custom_openssl.diff](http://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/9604982), and then `make clean && make`.

More details on why I used static links on Stack Overflow at [Coredump when compiling python with a custom openssl version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22409092).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete process I used  with Python 2.7.11.

---

In top level Python2.7.11 source dir:

1. Change `Modules/Setup.dist`, `Modules/Setup` : Uncomment `_ssl` section, comment out `_socket` (no-op if it's already commented out), uncomment and set SSL appropriately (path to your new ssl `lib/includes` etc.)

   Note: Modules/Setup file does not exist initially but after first run it get's content from Modules/Setup.dist i believe. Make sure changes are reflected in here before every run.
2. Apply patch: http://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/9604982
   (make distclean if previously ran make)

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/root/.local/aks/py-ssl/python2.7 --enable-shared

   # modify: Makefile -> set svnversion to ""

   make

   make altinstall
   ```

Comment: Confirmed that this approach works, and don't forget to change ``Modules/Setup`` file after the 1st failed run.

Comment: I've uncommented the lines in Modules/Setup.dist, then:

./configure --prefix='my build dir' --enable-shared
make
which fails:

dyld: Symbol not found: _GENERAL_NAME_free
  Referenced from: my_source_dir/libpython2.7.dylib
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

/bin/sh: line 1: 63299 Abort trap: 6           DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_source_dir ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed

make only fails when I include --enable-shared with configure. Conversely, make builds correctly with --enable-shared if I don't uncomment ssl lines in Setup.dist.

Answer (score 3):

### OpenSSL

```
cd /opt
sudo wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
sudo mkdir /opt/openssl
sudo tar xfvz openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz --directory /opt/openssl
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib
cd /opt/openssl/openssl-1.1.1q/
sudo ./config --prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl/ssl
sudo make
sudo make test
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

### Python 3.9.13

```
cd /usr/src 
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.13/Python-3.9.13.tgz 
sudo tar xzf Python-3.9.13.tgz
cd /usr/src/Python-3.9.13
sudo CFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl/include/" LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=/opt/openssl
sudo make altinstall -j6
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

### pip3

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 /usr/bin/pip3
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.06

Comment: Perfect, still works with "openssl-1.1.1w" and "Python-3.12.2" in March 2024

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same result until I got back to the logs for openssl.
There I saw that you need to use -fPIC when building openssl:
building '_ssl' extension:

```
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/feramos/Python-2.7.3/Include -I/home/feramos/Python-2.7.3 -c /home/feramos/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/feramos/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/feramos/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_ssl.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(x86_64cpuid.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

openssl-0.9.8g]# .config -fPIC
```

then, make, make install for openssl and then build Python again.

Answer (score 2):

I have a set of a couple of patches for static openssl and static libintl for 2 and 3 below.

For openssl (first patch) you have to set the env var OPENSSL_ROOT.

This is based on the patch from http://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/9604982 .

For Python 2.7.14:

https://gist.github.com/rkitover/2d9e5baff1f1cc4f2618dee53083bd35

https://gist.github.com/rkitover/afab7ed3ac7ce1860c43a258571c8ae1

For Python 3.6.3:

https://gist.github.com/rkitover/93d89a679705875c59275fb0a8f22b45

https://gist.github.com/rkitover/b18f19eafda3775a9652cc9cdf3ec914

Comment: Is the second patch for 2.7 and 3.6 respectively for the `iconv` check necessary?

Comment: The second patch I use because I use a static gettext, you may not need this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building Python2.7.13 and I see this same issue. For 2.7.13 you have to use "openssl1.0.0e" or above to make it work. I tried openssl-0.9.8g and it doesn't work.
And somehow I can't make it work just modifying Modules/Setup.dist so I have to manually compile that _ssl.o.
I guess this is because openssl-0.9.8g I provided is not working and it searched for system default libssl.so.10 which doesn't work either.

Comment: Just to add one thing, edit Modules/Setup.dist doesn't work for me. I have to edit Modules/Setup to make it work

Answer (score 1):

For **MAC OS HIGH Sierra**,
and **Python-3.5.6**
In the above answer the openssl installation is done using source,but if you install using brew it tells where the installed package is, so if you install openssl using brew

```
brew install openssl
```

This will install openssl at */usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/* this path needs to be updated in Modules/Setup.dist at

[Follow this answer which is mentioned above where the location of openssl installation is not mentioned to update the Modules/Setup.dist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939170/1797006)

In the above lines update SSL value to

```
SSL=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/
```

and uncomment the lines,
do a CMM and your python will get compiled with openssl.

Comment: That's not sufficiently different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939170/1797006 to make it a separate answer.

Comment: @KarlRichter... I was trying to make it simpler by using brew as brew tells the location of the installation that was the sole reason I wrote it separately. I have updated the answer as it was overlapping with the mentioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Wl,-rpath,/home/fds/rms/local/lib` to `LDPATH`.

Comment: Thanks par, but make is ignoring everything and only looking for the lib in the "standard" locations.

Comment: `-Wl,` passes everything after the `,` to the linker executable that is invoked by the compiler driver to specify where the binary that the linker is creating is statically supposed to look for runtime libraries. A runtime option is not going to help a buildtime problem. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Link-Options.html