# Coredump when compiling python with a custom openssl version

Tags: python, openssl, makefile

When compiling python-3.4.0rc3 with a local openssl-1.0.1f shared install, `make` prints no error but then I get the following core dump on make install or make test:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f131dd10510 in EVP_PKEY_CTX_dup () from /data2/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00007f131dd0284f in EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex () from /data2/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007f131e256ab5 in EVPnew (name_obj=0x7f131e46a500, digest=0x0, initial_ctx=0x7f131e459a40, cp=0x0, len=0) at /data2/soft/python3/Python-3.4.0rc3/Modules/_hashopenssl.c:410
#3  0x00007f131e25726e in EVP_new_md5 (self=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>) at /data2/soft/python3/Python-3.4.0rc3/Modules/_hashopenssl.c:799
#4  0x00000000004c7eef in ?? ()
```

Here is the complete list of commands used

```
tar -axf Python-3.4.0rc3.tgz
cd Python-3*
# For lzma and a pip-compatible openssl
export CFLAGS='-I/data2/soft/openssl/include/openssl -I/data2/local/include/'
export LDFLAGS='-L/data2/soft/openssl/lib -L/data2/local/lib/'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/data2/soft/openssl/lib:/data2/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
# Ready !
./configure --prefix=/data2/soft/python3
make
make install
```

*Notes:*

- OS is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
- pointing python to a custom location for the lzma lib located in
- openssl was built with `./config shared --openssldir=/data2/soft/openssl`
- openssl `make test` prints *ALL TESTS SUCCESSFUL.*
- without the custom openssl *FLAGS, make install is successful and I get these results for make test:
  `71 tests OK.
    tests failed:
      test_cmd_line test_gdb test_smtpnet test_ssl`

How can I fix this, or at least investigate what is going on ?

**Edit 1--5:**

The shared libs were generated correctly:

```
> ls /data2/soft/openssl/lib
drwxr-xr-x engines
-rw-r--r-- libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-r-xr-xr-x libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0
-r-xr-xr-x libssl.so.1.0.0
drwxr-xr-x pkgconfig
```

So I changed this in Setup :

```
SSL=/data2/soft/openssl/
_ssl _ssl.c \                               
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    $(SSL)/lib/libssl.a $(SSL)/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl
```

And I changed back LDFLAGS/CFLAGS accordingly. But there still is a -lssl when I run make clean && make, because of the _hashopen module:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -L/data2/local/lib/ -L/data2/local/lib/ -L/data2/local/lib/ -I/data2/local/include/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/data2/soft/python3/Python-3.4.0rc3/Modules/_hashopenssl.o -L/data2/local/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_hashlib.cpython-34m.so
```

I guess it is the one causing the cores, because they are still there... I tried adding similar stuff to Setup file, but there is no commented item for this one and creating it causes another more cryptic failure:

```
gcc -pthread   -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python Modules/python.o libpython3.4m.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil /data2/eoubrayrie/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.a /data2/eoubrayrie/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl   /data2/eoubrayrie/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.a /data2/eoubrayrie/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl   -lm  
libpython3.4m.a(config.o):(.data+0x158): undefined reference to `PyInit__hashopenssl'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit 6:**

- I couldn't find anyway to modify how _hashlib.so is generated, as there is too much Makefile magic involved (it doesn't appear anywhere, nor does '-lssl' yet both magically end up on the same  line together
- But I can get it linking dynamically to my own openssl through good old -I/-L:

  `ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_hashlib.cpython-34m.so
          libssl.so.1.0.0 => /data2/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f5605799000)
          libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /data2/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f56053bd000)`
- Now the only problem is, gdb `info shared` still tells me another one is used at core-time ... but how ?

  `From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
  0x00007ffff5465930  0x00007ffff5466e98  Yes         /data2/soft/python3/Python-3.4.0rc3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_hashlib.cpython-34m.so
  0x00007ffff5321220  0x00007ffff5351878  Yes         /opt/python-2.6-64/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
  0x00007ffff50d3100  0x00007ffff519b118  Yes         /opt/python-2.6-64/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`

  - `env | grep -F 'python-2.6-64'` -> shows nothing !
  - `grep -RF 'python-2.6-64' /etc/ld.so.*` -> idem
  - `gcc -print-search-dirs | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep python` -> idem
  - `find . -name '*.so*' | xargs ldd | grep ssl` -> only gives me the good ones
  - Level 1 dependencies don't require any wrong ssl version either. This was checked with: 
     `find . -name '*.so*' | xargs ldd | awk '/\t+[[:alnum:].]+ => [[:alnum:]./]+ \(/ {print $3}' | sort | uniq | xargs ldd | grep ssl`
  - `strace ./python  ./Tools/scripts/run_tests.py 2>&1 | grep python-2.6-64` -> shows nothing

So how does `ld` picks this wrong library if he cannot konow about it ?? It's not in any standard location (if it were in /lib I could understand...)

**Solution:**

Found how to statically link _hashlib thanks to [this OpenOffice bug](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=122647): though the `-Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL"` option didn't work either, it pointed me to the right lines in setup.py.

***TL;DR Here is the [patch to setup.py](https://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/9604982) I applied.***

And finally... it works !

@noloader I'm accepting your most complete answer as you help was invaluable, though the "exact" answer for anyone encountering this problem is to compile with the patch above.

Comment: "However gdb indeed showed me that the wrong libssl/libcrypto (the system ones) were used" - this is usually a sign that a dependency loaded first, and that dependency used the wrong OpenSSL library. Then, when your program was loaded, OpenSSL symbols were satisfied from the incorrect version of OpenSSL that was already loaded. Does LZMA library require `libcrypto`?

Comment: From the top level directory, try `grep -R -lssl *` and `grep -R -lcrypto *`. You might also try tracking `_ssl.c` and `_ssl.o`. If `-lssl` is being used, then `grep` will find it. For what its worth, autotools projects with recursive makefiles give me the most problems.

Comment: "So I guess I did not understand how you give the full path" - see my second answer below (sorry about that - the first was getting too long, and the second is more targeted).

Comment: "cannot find -l/data2/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.a" - drop the `-l` when specifying the archive `/data2/.../libssla.`; and add `-ldl` (OpenSSL will need it in this configuration).

Comment: how did you make out on this?

Comment: "But there still is a -lssl". I think you have two options. (1) `grep` the code for `-lssl` and delete it because its not needed; or (2) deleted Python and re-unpack it. Make the changes *before* `Setup.py` is run for the first time.

Comment: "But there still is a -lssl when I run make clean && make" - whoops.... re-run `./configure` after your changes and then `grep` the code to ensure there's no `-lssl` and friends.

Comment: "And finally... it works !" +1. Glad the suffering is over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> How can I fix this, or at least investigate what is going on ?
> ...
> export LDFLAGS='-L/data2/soft/openssl/lib -L/data2/local/lib/'
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/data2/soft/openssl/lib:/data2/local/lib/
> ```

I run into these problems a lot too because I avoid the crippled versions of OpenSSL shipped by Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, et al. For example, Ubuntu ships an OpenSSL that disables TLSv1.1 and TLS v1.2 (cf., [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576)).

You're probably loading the wrong version of the OpenSSL library. If you can get the misbehaving program under the debugger, issue `info shared` to see which `libcrypto` and `libssl` you are actually loading.

`ldd` might help too. Run it on the Pyhton executable: `ldd /data2/soft/python3/python`. I can only say it "may" help because the OpenSSL's are binary compatible, so you might only see a dependency on, for example, `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` (use `otool -L` on Mac OS X). Below I used an `rpath` to force linking against the libraries in `/usr/local/ssl/lib/`.

```
$ ldd my-test.exe 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd61ff000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f151528e000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1514e74000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1514c42000)
    ...
```

---

As a fix, you might try adding an `rpath`:

```
LDFLAGS='-L/data2/soft/openssl/lib -L/data2/local/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/data2/soft/openssl/lib'
```

A better fix would be to link to the static version of the OpenSSL library to avoid these problems all together. I believe you can do that with: `-Bstatic -lssl -lcrypto -Bdynamic -ldl`.

Personally, I don't even use `-Bstatic` because of different one-off problems. I open the Makefiles, remove all instances of `-lssl` `-lcrypto`, and add a full path to the archive to remove all ambiguity. For example, `/data2/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.a` and `/data2/soft/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a`.

*Note well*: an `rpath` is not honored on Mac OS X. More extreme measures are needed for Mac OS X because the linker does not honor `-Bstatic` either. You'll have to use the full path trick.

---

> ```
> openssl was built with ./config shared --openssldir=/data2/soft/openssl
> ```

Another thing... On Fedora, its not enough to specify `shared`. You need to add the following, too:

```
export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
```

Otherwise, the shared object is not built. If the 1.0.1f shared object is not built, you're probably getting a downlevel version supplied by the distro. You can check what was built *before* install with:

```
./config shared --openssldir=/data2/soft/openssl
make all

# Verify artifacts
find . -iname -libcrypto.*
find . -iname -libssl.*

# Proceed if OK
sudo make install
```

---

Finally, make sure that *all* of Python's dependencies are also using your version of OpenSSL and not the system's version of OpenSSL.

I recently suffered that problem when my program used my OpenSSL; but my program also used `libevent` and `libevent` used the system's version of OpenSSL. I fixed it by rebuilding `libevent` and forcing it to statically link to my version of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I go about changing it ? Will adding a _ssl.c: gcc ... line anywhere override the default behaviour ? My Makefile skills are rusted and this beast is 1600+ lines long !!

Here are the files you want to look at:

```
$ cd Python-3.4.0rc3

$ grep -R -- '-lcrypto' *
Modules/Setup.dist:#    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto

$ grep -R -- '-lssl' *
Modules/Setup.dist:#    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Here are the lines of interest in `Setup.dist`:

```
# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
#_ssl _ssl.c \
#   -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#   -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Uncomment the lines and change `Setup.dist` to the following. I keep my OpenSSL in `/usr/local/ssl`, so that's how mine is setup below (you should use `/data2/soft/openssl/lib/...`):

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl
```

Use the *full* path to the archive, and don't use *`-l`*. Be sure to add *`-ldl`* because OpenSSL needs it in this configuration.

Once you change `Setup.dist`, re-run `./configure` to effect the changes.

---

After changing the above line to, here's what I look like after a `configure`:

```
$ grep -R "libssl.a" *
Makefile:LOCALMODLIBS=  /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl 
Makefile:Modules/_ssl$(SO):  Modules/_ssl.o; $(BLDSHARED)  Modules/_ssl.o  /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl  -o Modules/_ssl$(SO)
Modules/Setup: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl 
Modules/Setup.dist: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl
```

---

You can test the static linking by using `ldd` or `otool -L`. You will *not* see an OpenSSL dependency. After `make`'ing, here's what I got:

```
$ find . -iname python
./python
$ ldd ./python
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff67709000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3aed8e1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3aed6dd000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f3aed4d9000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3aed257000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3aececc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3aedb14000)
```

No `libssl` or `libcrypto` dependencies to go wrong :) And `make test` ran fine (actually, one failed test due to a Python bug: [Issue 20896](http://bugs.python.org/issue20896)):

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_server_certificate (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/test/test_ssl.py", line 1373, in test_get_server_certificate
    _test_get_server_certificate('svn.python.org', 443, SVN_PYTHON_ORG_ROOT_CERT)
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/test/test_ssl.py", line 1354, in _test_get_server_certificate
    pem = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/ssl.py", line 902, in get_server_certificate
    with context.wrap_socket(sock) as sslsock:
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/ssl.py", line 344, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/ssl.py", line 540, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/jwalton/Python-3.4.0rc3/Lib/ssl.py", line 767, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:598)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 96 tests in 8.610s

FAILED (errors=1, skipped=3)
test test_ssl failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, just an observation after running though this with you:

```
$ make 
...

gcc -pthread -c -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement
  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include
  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Objects/capsule.o Objects/capsule.c
```

`-fwrapv` is really bad. Its used to make illegal programs work. Its better to fix the broken program and drop the `-fwrapv`. See Ian Lance Taylor's blog on [Signed Overflow](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120).

Comment: They have been trying to get rid of it for years... http://bugs.python.org/issue1621

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find anyway to modify how _hashlib.so is generated, as there is too much Makefile magic involved (it doesn't appear anywhere, nor does '-lssl' yet both magically end up on the same line together

`grep` is your friend ;)

```
$ grep -R _hashlib * | grep ssl
Lib/hashlib.py:        f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
Lib/hashlib.py:            _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
Lib/test/test_hashlib.py:            self.assertTrue(hasattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_md5'))
Lib/test/test_hashlib.py:            self.assertTrue(hasattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_sha1'))
Lib/test/test_hashlib.py:                constructor = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_'+algorithm, None)
Lib/test/ssltests.py:TESTS = ['test_asyncio', 'test_ftplib', 'test_hashlib', 'test_httplib',
Lib/test/time_hashlib.py:    print(" '_hashlib' 'openssl_hName' 'fast' tests the builtin _hashlib")
Modules/_hashopenssl.c:    "_hashlib.HASH",    /*tp_name*/
Modules/_hashopenssl.c:static struct PyModuleDef _hashlibmodule = {
Modules/_hashopenssl.c:    "_hashlib",
Modules/_hashopenssl.c:PyInit__hashlib(void)
Modules/_hashopenssl.c:    m = PyModule_Create(&_hashlibmodule);
PCbuild/build_ssl.py:# Script for building the _ssl and _hashlib modules for Windows.
PCbuild/build_ssl.py:# for the actual _ssl.pyd and _hashlib.pyd DLLs.
PCbuild/build_ssl.py:# it should configure and build SSL, then build the _ssl and _hashlib
setup.py:                exts.append( Extension('_hashlib', ['_hashopenssl.c'],
setup.py:                print("warning: openssl 0x%08x is too old for _hashlib" %
Tools/ssl/test_multiple_versions.py:    "test_asyncio", "test_ftplib", "test_hashlib", "test_httplib",
Tools/ssl/test_multiple_versions.py:MINIMAL_TESTS = ["test_ssl", "test_hashlib"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another partial answer...

> But I can get it linking dynamically to my own openssl through good old -I/-L:
>
> ...
>
> Now the only problem is, gdb info shared still tells me another one is used at core-time ... but how ?

That's your good old friends `-l` and `-L`. **Don't use them** because they do this sort of thing all the time (take it from a guy who has suffered it in the past). Instead, specify the *full* path to `libssl` and `libcrypto`. E.g., use `/data2/soft/openssl/lib/libssl.a`.

Comment: Obviously I would prefer it, however Setup change does not work for _hashlib and I could not get any clue about how -lssl is added to _hashlib compil or how to customize it in the Makefile. Nobody ever mentionned it on the net either :-(

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. We are using `apache httpd` + `mod_wsgi` + `python` + `django` and our c++ module for the `apache httpd` which also uses `openssl`. Now everything is loaded within one `httpd` process, correct version of openssl shared lib was loaded (1.0.0l) with our c++ module. But as soon as we access the web, python loads the `hashlib` and exactly the same problem appears - segfault in openssl called from python.

Normally python compiles with whatever `openssl` is available at **the default location** and there is no way how to specify it without fiddling with `setup.py` or makefiles. Python developers should add configure setting `--with_ssl=path`.

We installed new openssl libs and rebuild python and other binaries but with no success. We mapped default libssl.so and libcrypto.so to the new openssl binaries with no success. Finally after reading this thread I realized that probably wrong headers are being used while compiling python. And that was the problem. Follow the step to workaround the problem:

- there must not be incorrect version of `openssl` headers in `/usr/include` and default locations `/usr/local/ssl`, `/usr/contrib/ssl` (if you installed `openssl-devel` then uninstall it, or simply erase/rename the directory)

`yum remove openssl-devel`

- make symbolic link to your openssl installation from `/usr/local/ssl`

`ln -s /opt/openssl-1.0.1l /usr/local/ssl`

- ensure that the new openssl libs are accessible from `/usr/lib` (make symbolic links if it is not installed here)

`ln -s /opt/openssl-1.0.1l/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
...`

- now configure and clean build the `python`

Comment: Supplied a patch to the python for a new configure option --with-ssl (hopefully it will made its way to the release): http://bugs.python.org/issue21541

Comment: Has your patch been merged in Python master?

Comment: @dex: I did not checked since that... looking at current version 3.5 I could not find that, no `--with-ssl` option

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run python 2.7.11 with non-default SSL after patching fix mentioned here https://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/9604982

However, with this it's not building _socket module which is required by many other modules. for example, easy_install / pip started failing with error Importerr: no module named _socket

In Module/Setup.dist, am i suppose to uncomment or comment the line
_socket socketmodule.o 
?

I see socketmodule.o and timemodule.o getting generated. but not _socket.so
Am i missing something ?

Comment: No idea, I haven't been working with this patch recently... you should probably ask a new question (with a link to this one)

Comment: Actually, commenting out line "_socket socketmodule.c timemodule.c" in Modules/Setup.dist resolves this issue. Make sure Module/Setup is reflecting this change as well.