# Issues whiles compiling Calibre with OpenSSL

Tags: python, macos, openssl, qmake, configure

I have all the dependencies installed for compiling calibre on mac, but when I run `python setup.py build` I get the following error:

```
...
####### Building extension lzma_binding #######

####### Building extension dukpy #######

####### Building extension hunspell #######

####### Building extension _regex #######

####### Building extension monotonic #######

####### Building extension speedup #######

####### Building extension zlib2 #######

####### Building extension certgen #######
Compiling certgen
gcc -Wall -DNDEBUG -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fPIC -D_OSX -fno-common -dynamic -O3
  -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
  -c /Users/jeanlinux/projects/Desktop/calibre/src/calibre/utils/certgen.c
  -o /Users/jeanlinux/projects/Desktop/calibre/build/objects/certgen/certgen.o
/Users/jeanlinux/projects/Desktop/calibre/src/calibre/utils/certgen.c:11:10:
  fatal error: 'openssl/rand.h' file not found
#include <openssl/rand.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I have uninstalled openssl using `brew uninstall openssl` and installed back but i still get the same error.

Comment: How did you configure? Also see [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5937337).

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work either, this is a little weird because i can verify locate `<openssl/rand.h>` and all other headers under `/usr/local/ssl/include` I even tried setting the CPPFLAGS  variable with `CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib"  python2 setup.py build` but still fails.