# how to include ssl with python build on MacOS

Tags: python

While building python from source on a MacOS, I accidntally overwrote the python that came with MacOS, now it doesn't have SSL. I tried to build again by running `--with-ssl` option

```
./configure --with-ssl
```

but when I subsequently ran `make`, it said this

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _ssl               dl              
imageop            linuxaudiodev      ossaudiodev     
readline           spwd               sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

It's not clear to me from looking at `setup.py` what I'm supposed to do to find the "necessary bits". What can I do to build python with SSL on MacOS?

Comment: Although a different *OS*, might be related: [\[SO\]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open `setup.py` and find method `detect_modules()`. It has some lines like (2.7.11 for me):

```
    # Detect SSL support for the socket module (via _ssl)
    search_for_ssl_incs_in = [
                          '/usr/local/ssl/include',
                          '/usr/contrib/ssl/include/'
                         ]
    ssl_incs = find_file('openssl/ssl.h', inc_dirs,
                         search_for_ssl_incs_in
                         )
    if ssl_incs is not None:
        krb5_h = find_file('krb5.h', inc_dirs,
                           ['/usr/kerberos/include'])
        if krb5_h:
            ssl_incs += krb5_h
    ssl_libs = find_library_file(self.compiler, 'ssl',lib_dirs,
                                 ['/usr/local/ssl/lib',
                                  '/usr/contrib/ssl/lib/'
                                 ] )

    if (ssl_incs is not None and
        ssl_libs is not None):
        exts.append( Extension('_ssl', ['_ssl.c'],
                               include_dirs = ssl_incs,
                               library_dirs = ssl_libs,
                               libraries = ['ssl', 'crypto'],
                               depends = ['socketmodule.h']), )
    else:
        missing.append('_ssl')
```

So it seems that you need SSL and Kerberos. Kerberos comes installed with Mac. So You need to install `openssl`. You can do it with `brew`:

```
brew install openssl
```

`openssl` headers could be installed in a path different than Python will search. So issue

```
locate ssl.h
```

and add the path to `search_for_ssl_incs_in`. For example for me it is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/include/openssl/ssl.h
```

So I should add `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/include/` to `search_for_ssl_incs_in`.

Don't forget that these are for Python 2.7.11. But the process should be same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed the paths to `/opt/local/...` for the MacPorts OpenSSL. The built succeeded, but Python failed to import the `_ssl` module due to undefined symbols. Installing OpenSSL [from source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) solved the problem, using the default paths in CPython's `setup.py`.

Comment: I had the same problem but was able to get it working with openSSL from Homebrew. Here's how https://stackoverflow.com/a/46476640/2934226

Comment: There is absolutely no need to edit `setup.py`. Just make sure to set the CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS variables when running configure: `CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" ./configure`

Answer (score 12):

First of all, MacOS only includes LibreSSL 2.2.7 libraries and no headers, you really want to install OpenSSL using homebrew:

```
$ brew install openssl
```

The openssl formula is a *keg-only* formula because the LibreSSL library is shadowing OpenSSL and Homebrew will not interfere with this. This means that you can find OpenSSL not in `/usr/local` but in `/usr/local/opt/openssl`. But Homebrew includes the necessary command-line tools to figure out what path to use.

You then need to tell `configure` about these. If you are building Python 3.7 or newer, use the `--with-openssl` switch:

```
./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
```

If you are building an older release, set the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` environment variables:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
./configure
```

and the Python configuration infrastructure takes it from there.

Know that *now ancient* Python releases (2.6 or older, 3.0-3.4) only work with OpenSSL 1.0.x and before, which no longer is installable from homebrew core.

Comment: 2022 update: you have a choice between OpenSSL 1.1.1 and 3.0 (both work on recent CPython versions). In `brew` commands you might have to specify `openssl@1.1` or `openssl@3` (e.g. `brew install openssl@1.1` and `brew --prefix openssl@1.1`). As of Python 3.11.0, OpenSSL 1.1.1 is often the default, so you might prefer that right now. But that might change soon.