# How can I compile Python 3.6.2 on macOS with openSSL from homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, compilation, openssl

I'm trying to compile Python 3.6.2 on macOS 10.11 according to the instructions on https://bugs.python.org/issue29095.

I've used homebrew to install openSSL to the standard location and then added LDFLAGS, CFLAGS, and CPPFLAGS to my env:

```
$ printenv | grep FLAGS
LDFLAGS=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/lib/
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/include/openssl
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/include/openssl
```

Then in that same shell, I compile Python to the custom location required for my use case:

```
$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/oebuild/python/python-3.6.1
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

However, the SSL module doesn't get built. The build log says this:

> Python build finished successfully!
>   The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
>   _gdbm                 _ssl                  ossaudiodev
>   spwd
>   To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Comment: [How do I compile Python 3.4 with custom OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23548188/608639), [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5937337/608639), [Building python with openssl support](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254974/56041), etc.

Comment: And some others... [How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361569), [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858), [Python and OpenSSL version reference issue on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37690054), [Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899573), [Using Python with homebrew on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441252), etc...

Comment: And some more... [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

None of the previous answers I found earlier worked for me, but I did eventually figure this out with the help of another answer not mentioned earlier. Here was the actual fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20740964/2934226

Basically, CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS can't be set in the environment; you need to set them alongside the configure command, like this:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I[openSSL install location]/include" LDFLAGS="-L[openSSL install location]/lib" [other flags here]
```

And then after compiling and installing, it worked!

```
$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
```

Here are the things that didn't work, and why:

[How do I compile Python 3.4 with custom OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548188/how-do-i-compile-python-3-4-with-custom-openssl) doesn't help because you can't set LDFLAGS, CFLAGS, or CPPFLAGS in the environment; setup.py doesn't pass them along to the actual compilation steps. And even if setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH might work, you don't want to do that because it's dangerous (see http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html). Finally, --with-ssl isn't a valid configure argument, and the patch listed there to add it doesn't apply cleanly.

[Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl) doesn't apply when you're trying to build something from source, rather than trying to get an an already-compiled dylib to find a relocated library. Furthermore, making symlinks in /usr/local is dangerous, and can cause programs to compile against the newer headers but use the older system binaries.

[how to include ssl with python build on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774171/how-to-include-ssl-with-python-build-on-macos) doesn't work properly. Editing setup.py to add the lib and include directories for where you've installed my openSSL *partially* works, and lets you compile in SSL support. Alas, they aren't importable because the old version is still getting used:

```
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_hashlib              _ssl
```

[...]

```
building '_ssl' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I./Include -I/oebuild/python/python-3.6.1/include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Include -I/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1 -c /oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_ssl.o -L/oebuild/python/python-3.6.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so
building '_hashlib' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I./Include -I/oebuild/python/python-3.6.1/include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Include -I/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1 -c /oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_hashopenssl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_hashopenssl.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/oebuild/python/src/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_hashopenssl.o -L/oebuild/python/python-3.6.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_hashlib.cpython-36m-darwin.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: dlopen(build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback
  Referenced from: build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_hashlib" since importing it failed: dlopen(build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_hashlib.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _HMAC_CTX_copy
  Referenced from: build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_hashlib.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_hashlib.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

`otool -L` shows the problem:

```
$ otool -L build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin_failed.so 
build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.6/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin_failed.so:
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

(CRYPTO_THREADID was introduced in version 1.0.0, according to https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Threads(3)#HISTORY)

Comment: Note that you can get the "openSSL install location" with `brew --prefix openssl`, so your command line can be `./configure CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" `

Comment: This works not just for python3 installs, but also for python2. (I tried with 2.7.6)

Comment: where is the ./configure file resides

Comment: Inside the python source directory

Answer (score 14):

No answer above worked for me, for Python 3.8 (currently in beta).

Instead, what worked for me (July 2019, updated January 2022):

```
brew install openssl
./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
```

Comment: This worked for me; though on M1 it took the following change: `./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)`

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had success like this.

```
  brew update
  brew install openssl

  # these were suggested by brew itself.

  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"

  # vanilla compilation

  ./configure
  make
```

Comment: Thank you - only this one worked once adding the additional `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` parameter to my `./configure` command.
I've written a shell wrapper for OSX to assist in my own builds which is available here: https://github.com/danstreeter/osx-python-builder - contributions welcome =)

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with building from pyenv all day so figured I'd contribute the method for doing it in 2020:

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
PYTHON_BUILD_HOMEBREW_OPENSSL_FORMULA=openssl@1.0 pyenv install 3.6.2
```

or in my case, 3.4.10 (what I tested this with)

I know this question isn't for pyenv specifically but I found this thread looking for help with pyenv and I'm sure others have too.

Note that this version of openssl is (currently) 1.0.2t

Comment: Thanks for this answer, as it's really the easiest solution for users of both `brew` and `pyenv`. However, don't forget to also check `$CONFIGURE_OPTS` and unset or override if necessary (`CONFIGURE_OPTS=""` or `CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)"`) at the start of the second command above. Mine was set in `.zshrc` to specify `openssl@1.1` in order to steer `rbenv` toward using `openssl@1.1`, and I needed to override it to get older Pythons built using `pyenv`.

Comment: This worked for me, but with OpenSSL v3. I'm on an intel Mac.

```
PYTHON_BUILD_HOMEBREW_OPENSSL_FORMULA=openssl@3 pyenv install 3.6
```