# Cannot let python compiler point to openSSL

Tags: python, openssl, flags

I was trying to let my python complier points to the openSSL (mac and vs code dev) since I am getting this error when I compile my code:
`ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with LibreSSL 2.8.3. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168`
I am trying to follow another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457404/how-can-i-compile-python-3-6-2-on-macos-with-openssl-from-homebrew) that set up CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS with `./configure` command. (I once tried export it in PATH Variable in my ./zshrc file but it does not work)

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib"
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include"
```

I do not have `./configure` exec in my python3 set up. The only configure exec is python3-config but it does not support any configure set command. Anyone know how should I find a work-around way to fix it? Thanks

```
python3-config CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include"
(Not work) Usage: /opt/homebrew/bin/python3-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--abiflags|--configdir|--embed]
```

With python3-config, it seems only support query flags but not set flags.

Comment: Configure only applies if you are going to recompile Python itself.  Python scripts are not compiled; they get their libraries on the fly.  You can try using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the other version.