# Python 3.7 Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSLmodule is not available

Tags: python, ssl

I am in the process of installing Python 3.7 on my dedicated server running centos 6.10
After jumping through some hoops to try and do this, I am reaching yet another error.  Using Python 3.7 to try and stay up to date, it is a rather common issue to have SSL issues with pip installation.  I came to the conclusion that the best way to fix this problem was to get the right version of OpenSSL.  So I did so, and edited my python modules/Setup.dist file, reconfigured it, reran make altinstall, and while everything seemed fine.  For some reason, the command `Python3.7` which was the command I used for running this python before, suddenly became unrecognized as a command, while in the Python3.7 directory was a folder `python` now which when executed (after editing the environment path turned on the Python3.7.  Beforehand this was not the case, and it was just `Python3.7`  Does anyone know what could have happened here?

Also, I am about at the end of my wits with this whole SSL thing, and I have read about every article under the sun it feels like.  Here is a list of some commands I executed as of recent:

```
#Unpacked Python3.7 into /usr/src directory
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
make altinstall

#installation failed from no '_ctypes' module

yum install libffi-devel

#repeat configure above
#yaaay python
#Successfully installed pip-10.0.1 setuptools-39.0.1 was the final message of the installation

Python3.7 -m venv /my/project/directory/ENV
pip install {library}

#this is where my issues began with SSL
```

Logs:

```
(ENV) [root@s1.1.1.1 ProjectDirectory]# pip3 install twisted
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however, the SSL module in Python is not available.
Collecting twisted
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/twisted/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/twisted/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/twisted/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/twisted/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/twisted/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/twisted/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/twisted/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twisted
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSLmodule is not available.")) - skipping
```

So I was like ok cool.  No worries.  The most recent version of Python can't even get pip3 right out of the box.  Wonderful.  Well, I started searching google as we do and came to the conclusion that everybody was just reconfiguring their python again and it magically worked.  Not sure why, but ok.  I was into it.  I found this article:

https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/

Thinking ok cool.  If I can get python3.7 SSL, then it should get pip3 to work right?  Wrong.  Unfortunately, if I kick on Python3.7 in the new strange way I mentioned above, and type `import ssl` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/src/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Could anyone provide me with some assistance?  I am sort of lost in an ocean, and I don't know how to swim...  Anything would be awesome, but I am a noob to this server admin stuff so the more simple it is, the better :)  Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
By the way

```
yum install openssl
```

and

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

both results in 'already installed' flag...  So I don't think that's another solution.  However when I did the install manually I used version 1.1.1 because I know that 3.7 dropped support for a few different versions of OpenSSL for whatever reason.  The one that is already yum installed is 1.0.2 I think.  I don't know if there is a capacity for the centos 6.10 platform though as far as version limits.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location) would be handy for you :)

Comment: yes.  Sorry I forgot to mention I did what the answer to that question says.  No fix.  I put OpenSSL in /usr/local/openssl so that it wouldn't mess with default SSL installation because I am trying not to ruin the server as best as I can for obvious reasons.  In configuring Python, I edited Modules/Setup.dist and then configured it.  Unless you were referring to something besides the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm halfway thinking it would be easier to just ditch python 3.7 and go with 3.6 or... maybe even 2.7 but I wanted to stay with the tide and shift to python 3 now so I don't need to worry about it along the line

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue on my **mac OS** where I couldn't install anything or even upgrade `pip` from within a virtual environment due to SSL issues.

#### What worked for me was doing the following *from inside the virtual environment*

1. `sudo chown -R ${whoami} /usr/local/Cellar` followed by
2. `brew install openssl`

#### What is the `${whoami}` in the first command?

It's a placeholder; what you should put there when you run the command is your actual current user.

If you don't know your user, in the command line type

`whoami`

The output is your user.  So if you type that and get `johnsmith` as output, when you run the first command, you'll replace "`${whoami}`" with "`johnsmith`" like this:

`sudo chown -R johnsmith /usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: this didn't work for me :(
does not work with new version of python installed on mac

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you've already figured this out, but you have to make sure that while building python that it can find openssl libraries.

So specifically:
  If you're not using the system ssl libraries or they're not in your path, at --configure you need to specify where they are. I would give you the exact line but I myself havn't done this recently.
  If you've done this correctly, you will not see a report at the end of the build that python skipped building 'ssl' module.
  When you see the error you have above about (_ssl), this specifically means python was not built with it.
  You'll face the same problem in 3.6 if you using the same steps without changing --configure.

Answer (score 2):

Upload `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb` file on `\Anaconda3\DLLs` Then your problem will be solved
Those files may be available in `\Anaconda3\Library\bin` directory or you can download from the official website.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while attempting to compile Python 3.7.2 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Make sure you have all the dependencies required to build Python's built-in modules. Run `make 2>&1 | tee make.txt` after `configure` and look for warnings of modules that failed to build. If modules fail to build, Python won't fail the install it simply won't build those modules leading to the kind of error you're seeing.

After installing the dependencies, make sure to run `configure` again.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I think I ended up figuring something out for it...  I don't remember at this point, I may have just given up and installed 3.6.2 or something...  Otherwise it had something to do with where it was installing python and I just needed to use a different command or something...  I don't remember now :/  Thanks for the help anyway though, if I run into this issue again I will refer back.

Answer (score -1):

Configure option "--with-openssl" works for me