# On CentOS, how do I build Python 3.9 from source while incorporating my openssl module?

Tags: python, openssl, centos7, python-3.9

I'm trying to build Python 3.9.1 with SSL support on CentOS 7.

```
[myuser@server Python-3.9.1]$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
[myuser@server Python-3.9.1]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

Running this command

```
sudo ./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/openssl/lib" --with-ssl
```

followed by "make" worked for Python 3.7, but when i run the above on 3.9 and then run make I get this output

```
...
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_lzma                 _tkinter              _uuid              
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
_abc                  atexit                pwd                
time                                                           


Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_hashlib              _ssl                                     


Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381

running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-3.9
copying and adjusting /usr/src/Python-3.9.1/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.9
copying and adjusting /usr/src/Python-3.9.1/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.9
copying and adjusting /usr/src/Python-3.9.1/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.9
changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/idle3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/2to3 from 644 to 755
renaming build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.9/pydoc3.9
renaming build/scripts-3.9/idle3 to build/scripts-3.9/idle3.9
renaming build/scripts-3.9/2to3 to build/scripts-3.9/2to3-3.9
/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Tools/gdb/libpython.py python-gdb.py
gcc -pthread -c -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/openssl/include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Programs/_testembed.o ./Programs/_testembed.c
gcc -pthread -L/usr/local/openssl/lib    -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o Programs/_testembed Programs/_testembed.o libpython3.9.a -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm   -lm 
sed -e "s,@EXENAME@,/usr/local/bin/python3.9," < ./Misc/python-config.in >python-config.py
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's,\$(\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)),\$\{\1\},g' < Misc/python-config.sh >python-config
```

So evidently Python 3.9 has NOT been built with SSL.  What else do I need to do to build Python 3.9 with the openssl module I have installed?

Comment: This might be because it might not be able to find your openssl libraries. What did your `./configure` say about your OpenSSL? More specifically, we are looking at line `checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works...`.

Comment: This is usually an issue with your `./configure` not being able to find your OpenSSL libraries and link it.

Comment: Similar issue has been raised in the [Python bug issue 34028](https://bugs.python.org/issue34028)

Comment: @AmitSingh, The line "checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes" appears.  There is also a warning, "configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-ssl"

Comment: The correct argument is `--with-openssl` probably. Can you try with that?

Comment: Okay, sorry I missed this part. You have to specify the openssl directory for that to work. Be sure to specify it as the directory that contains the `lib` folder

Comment: Gotcha.  So I was able to run configure with "--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl" but when I ran "make" after I still got the same error as reported in the question.

Comment: Can you try doing this with `yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel tk-devel uuid-devel`? This is probably a case of missing libraries then.

Comment: I ran the command you have above, then ran the configure (with openssl) command and make but still get the same "Could not build the ssl module!" message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226790/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-dave).

Comment: What if **before** *configure* (and *make*) you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/openssl/bin` (I assume that's your path to *libcrypto* and *libssl*)?

Comment: Just a note on your approach: `sudo configure` is usually wrong. You configure, build and test as regular user, only if you install system-wide you use `sudo make install` or something similar.

Comment: @ChristiFati, I have files "/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so" and  "/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a" so should my export command be "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/openssl/lib"?

Comment: @Dave, yes, add the path to your custom built *libcrypto.so*, and see if it works.

Comment: @Dave you can try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939170/14475852)

Answer (score 6):

### Python3.10 source build on CentOS 7.6

The above posts were very helpful to guide me to my solution. I want to share in case someone else could use this:

#### First the development libs

1. `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y`
2. `sudo yum install openssl11-devel libffi-devel bzip2-devel xz-devel -y`

   - for static linking use `openssl11-static`

### Then configure

So for some reason CentOS ships `openssl1.1.1` but it is installed in a way that doesn't jive with Python's `configure` script.

```
# note that we #include <openssl/foo.h>, so the OpenSSL headers have to be in
    # an 'openssl' subdirectory

    if ! $found; then
        OPENSSL_INCLUDES=
        for ssldir in $ssldirs; do
            { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for openssl/ssl.h in $ssldir" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for openssl/ssl.h in $ssldir... " >&6; }
            if test -f "$ssldir/include/openssl/ssl.h"; then
                OPENSSL_INCLUDES="-I$ssldir/include"
                OPENSSL_LDFLAGS="-L$ssldir/lib"
                OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto"
```

Since Python is including headers a subfolder is desired: `$ssldir/include/openssl/ssl.h`

I just created a new folder with the correct layout:

```
/opt/openssl111/
├── include
│   └── openssl
│       └── *.h
└── lib
    ├── libcrypto.so
    └── libssl.so
```

Once in place, the trifecta:

1. `./configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto --with-openssl=/opt/openssl111/`

   - `lto` is link time optimization
2. `make -j8`
3. `make altinstall` (installs in `/usr/local/` not to overwrite system python)

Answer (score 6):

When you compile Python, you need to tell it which OpenSSL headers and libraries to use.

First, install openssl11-devel:

```
sudo yum install --assumeyes openssl11-devel
```

Second, before running "`./configure"` set `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` from the values emitted by `pkg-config`

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags openssl11)"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $(pkg-config --libs openssl11)"
```

Third, configure and build as normal:

```
./configure --prefix=/some/where/dir
   # ... etc ...
```

This is the most reliable way to get the correct flags passed to the compiler and linker.  It's also worth checking that there aren't any conflicting values being passed into the `CFLAGS` / `LDFLAGS` environment variables, which might stymie your efforts.

This assumes that you have the `openssl-devel` package installed, obviously. :-)

Comment: after installing openssl11-devel, this solution worked for me.

Comment: I am a a python newbie and this helped running me get my requirements running python running on centos 7, also with `yum install openssl11 openssl11-devel` and `./configure --enable-optimizations --with-lto` Other global dependencies still require OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because of missing development libraries that should be installed. To install them, as per [Python Developer installation docs](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#linux) for CentOS, run

```sh
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-builddep python3
```

Run the following to build Python

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

In case you want to build it with your custom SSL library, pass the argument `--with-openssl` along with your library path. The path should contain a `lib` folder containing the required files.

```sh
./configure --with-openssl=<your-openssl-library-path>
```

Comment: I tried your version with the "./configure --with-openssl" command and after running "/usr/local/bin/python3  -m pip install --upgrade pip" I get a warning, "WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available" so I don't think the steps worked.

Comment: Why were you running `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`? Did it get installed but is now giving you this warning?

Comment: Your `make` is probably still giving errors. Can you check the logs?

Answer (score 1):

**CentOS 7, Python3.9, OpenSSL1.1.1k      (Packages Used)**

This method works for installing Python 3.9 (from source) while incorporating the OpenSSL socket module. OpenSSL package also installed from source (away from base OS / yum package install locations). Summary: All packages directed to install in /usr/local/

**Install Developments Tools for base OS (CentOS 7) via yum:**

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo yum install gcc open-ssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel -y
```

There are likely a lot more required packages, scurry the internet to find all that are needed for your OS Version. Fair amount of roadblocks result from missing development packages not already installed while compiling/installing openssl & python3.9

**Install OpenSSL From source First:**

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1k
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**Retrieve & tar Python3.9 package from source:**

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tgz
tar -xzf Python-3.9.6.tgz
cd ~/Python3.9.6
```

**Edit Python3.9 configuration file before installing Python3.9:**

```
cd /path/to/Python3.9/source/directory/
nano Setup
```

Uncomment the following lines:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl

_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Note:  Change "SSL=/usr/local/ssl" to "SSL=/usr/local/openssl"

**Install Python3.9 From Source w/ with SSL Module, supplied by OpenSSL package (already installed via source, see above):**

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/openssl/lib64" --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl
sudo make
sudo make altinstall          #installs Python3.9.6 into /usr/local
```

CPPFLAGS -->   compiler flag option
LDFLAGS  -->   linker flag option

**Upgrade pip for Python3.9:**

```
python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Python3.9 -m pip    --> Uses most recent version of pip install (i.e. pip3)

**Sym-Link Shared Library Files from OpenSSL for Python3:**

```
find / -name libssl.so.3
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/openssl/lib64/libssl.so.3  /usr/lib64/libssl.so.3
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/openssl/lib64/libcrypto.so.3  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3
ldconfig          #dynamic linker
```

Comment: *Install OpenSSL From source First*?  That's not necessary.  OpenSSL 1.1.1 is available on Centos/RHEL 7 in the `openssl11...` set of packages.  `yum install openssl11-devel`. See the answer already posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73530495/4756299

Comment: @AndrewHenle If your sysadmin is willing to install openssl11-devel for you, they sure will also provide you with Python 3.9. (I can understand hesitation to install 3.10 or higher as some old scripts cannot handle double digits in the minor version number correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the key:

> Following modules built successfully but were removed because they
> could not be imported:
> _hashlib              _ssl

What could cause this to happen is that the libraries installed in a non-standard location can't be loaded. So, locate the module (it is built, after all) and run `ldd` on it. See it's manpage for further detail and keep in mind that Python modules are shared objects (or DLLs on MS Windows). It will probably show a missing dependency on libssl.so. In order to resolve that, configure Linux' dynamic linker to pick up the file. I'd like to refer you to `man ld.so` for instructions, no use duplicating that info here.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding -- you want me to run "ldd" on what module?

Comment: On the built `_ssl` module.

Answer (score -1):

```
# try the following:
export CC="gcc"
export CXX="g++"
export CPP="cpp"
export F90="gfortran"
export F77="gfortran"
export FC="gfortran"

dnf install gcc bzip2-devel tk-devel openssl-devel uuid-devel sqlite-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel xz-lzma-compat xz-devel libffi-devel libnsl2-devel
./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations
make -j
make install
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Although the code above might be a valid answer for the question, adding comments/explanations would help those looking at your answer.